# Can I change the size of a symbol in EagleCAD?

Tags: eaglecad, symbol

I am new to EagleCAD and I just finished generating a new complementary MOSFET in a TSOP-6 package. Everything was fine until I pulled the new component into my schematic and realized that it was way too big in comparison to the other components.

Is there a way to shrink the symbol without having to redraw it from scratch?

Comment: There may be a way to do this using their inherent programming language, but learning to use it would be much slower than redrawing from scratch.  Chalk it up to experience, and be glad you're not talking about remaking 50 parts!

Comment: In the end does it really matter? Schematics are topological so the size is irrelevant as long as the pins are on the standard 0.1" grid.

Answer (score 6):

If you've made the part just go into the library and change it. There is no resize tool so you will have to redraw it.

Comment: Why is this downvoted? Is there a way to resize it? If so, inform the person and explain the downvote.

Comment: +1 because this answer is correct.  I don't see why it is downvoted either.

Comment: There is ULP called 'psscale', but for symbols with pins it will only cause problems (going off grid, not scaling the pins length, etc.). It's good for logos, but not part symbols. So really redrawing is the only option +1.

Answer (score 0):

(I would just comment on [Tom Carpenter](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/users/53368/tom-carpenter)'s answer, but SE doesn't work that way. But I stand on his shoulders)

In practice, I found the `psscale` ULP to be better than starting from scratch:

- scale part up using ULP:

  - create SCR from current symbol - *integer* scales shouldn't drift too badly
  - create new symbol and run SCR
- group select and move pins

  - e.g. on my square IC part this was 4 group/move operations
- Then you **do** have to reconnect all the pins again manually